# Haswell integrated graphics with VGA (D-SUB) port max resolution problem

Tags: xorg

I recently bought new laptop with two graphics cards: intel 4600 and Geforce 765M.  Having seen this topic ([Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)) I abandoned any hope of getting the nvidia chip getting hold of my external display. However, I'm facing another problem, far bigger for me: the haswell chip does not recognize all resolutions my display has to offer (It's a Eizo S2402W connected via the VGA port). It stops at 1600x1200 and I need a native resolution of 1920x1200.

Things I tried so far:

1. Installed a new kernel - 3.10 from kernel.ubuntu.com - no change
2. Tried to insert new mode with `xrandr` - to no avail

My system is:
i7-4700mq/8gb/gtx765m/intel4600
ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 with both stock kernel and 3.10 for saucy
I also installed the nvidia-319 driver for testing of bumblebee

How could I set the native resolution of 1920x1200 when the `xrandr` does not allow that?

**UPDATE**:

In `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` the correct Modeline is present, but it is not available in `xrandr`:

```
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x0.0  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync (74.6 kHz eP)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  202.50  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (93.8 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[   617.921] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[   618.984] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 3600x1080
[   618.986] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@59.9 on pipe 0 using eDP1, position (0, 0), rotation normal
[   619.012] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1680x1050@60.0 on pipe 1 using VGA1, position (1920, 0), rotation normal
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I checked my monitor with computer from work which runs Core i5-2410M with Intel HD Graphics 3000 on board, everything works fine. Version of Ubuntu is 12.04 x86_64 with stock kernel 3.2.0-51.

So taking into consideration that the intel chip (both of the actually) is aware of the resolutions my display reports (EDID):

**UPDATE 3**:

I updated the xorg griver: `xserver-xorg-video-intel` to version 2:2.21.14+git20130806.6004870d-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring with no success.

**UPDATE 4**:

Just bought DVI2HDMI cable and bam, full HD resolution now works fine.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't this a limitation of the interface you are using (VGA)?

Comment: No, it is not a limitation of the interface. I worked on this display using different computer (much older one) and it worked fine with max resolution.

Comment: Have you installed any available proprietary drivers?

Comment: When I launch jockey (the app responsible for available proprietary drivers) it does not detect anything. It's not a problem though because I need to have Intel GPU working which runs a open source i915 driver.

Comment: I have the exact same problem reported here.  I have the April 2016 drivers on Windows10.  Dell 24 inch 1920x1200 monitor.   The Intel website strangely says 1920x1200 on VGA should work.